# Ajax Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I don't know why the console return me this uncaught syntax ...
Help me plz !

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#idval").change(function() {

    var id = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
      url: 'verif.php',
      type: 'GET',
      data: 'user=' + id,

      success: function(server_response) {
        var session = $(server_response).html();

        if (id == session) {
          console.log($("#" + d));
        } else {
          console.log("You shall not pass!");
        }

      },
      error: function(server_response, statut, error) {
        console.log("Can't be linked !");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

When the user enter an `id`, the server check if the `id` is on the database. If it is, the server return the `id` in the console if it isn't, the server should return "string", but it return the uncaught ....

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of `var session = $(server_response).html();`? (Which is, btw, almost certainly the problem.) If you just want the text, just use `server_response` directly.

Answer (score 5):

This line:

```
var session = $(server_response).html();
```

doesn't make sense. If the server echos back the ID on success, just use `server_response` directly.

```
  success: function(server_response) {
    if (id == server_response) { // <== Here
      console.log($("#" + id));  // <== Also fixed apparent typo on this line,
                                 //     but that's not the reason for the
                                 //     error you're getting
    } else {
      console.log("You shall not pass!");
    }
  },
```

`$(server_response)` asks jQuery to use `server_response` either as HTML and built DOM elements or as a CSS selector. "Unrecognized expression" suggests that it doesn't look like HTML and so jQuery tries to use it as a selector, but it's not a valid selector.

---

In an answer that should have been a comment, you said you've updated the code to (mostly) the above but it's still not working, and you've shown us this PHP code:

```
while ($idval = $reponse->fetch()) {
    if ($idval){
        echo $idval['user'];
    }
    else{
        echo "nope";
    }
}
```

If `if (id == server_response)` isn't working, that tells us that `id` isn't an **exact** match for `server_response`. A common cause for that with PHP scripts is that you're inadvertently including whitespace before or after the code where you output your response, usually newlines somewhere, often at the end.

We can trim those off on modern browsers via `server_response.trim()` or to support older browsers, using jQuery's `$.trim` via `$.trim(server_response)`:

```
  success: function(server_response) {
    if (id == $.trim(server_response)) { // <== Here
      console.log($("#" + id));
    } else {
      console.log("You shall not pass!");
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare any "d" in your code but you use this in `console.log`

```
console.log($("#"+d));
```

but it should be:

```
console.log($("#"+id));
```

you missed the `i`.

Comment: That's true, that doesn't match the reported symptom, and is likely a typo in the question or a line inserted to diagnose the actual problem.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why you did this `var session = $(server_response).html();`

you can just use 'server_response'. no need to use `$` sign.

Also please correct the syntax of `console.log($("#" + d));` to `console.log($("#" + id));` 
as i don't see that you have defined `d` anywhere.

hope this will help you.